# Django log configuration ignored despite config

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to set up logging in my Django app.
My logging configuration is defined in the settings.py:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'test': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'test'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG'
            }
        }
}

import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

Then in my code:

```
import logging

...

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug("debug")
logger.info("info")
logger. warning("warn")
logger.error("error")
logger.critical("critical")
```

But I only get:

```
warn
error
critical
```

The log level and the formatter dont work.
Why is my configuration not taken into account ?